# send text to the input line console c++

Tags: c++, input, stream, console

I need to output to the console a string that the user could edit and press Enter. After that I could continue to work with the string. The Windows platform. The C ++ language. Thank you.

P.S.

the fgets function reads a string from the stream. I need that when performing fgets on the screen already had text that can be edited.

I need a library similar to the GUI readline, I do the autocompletion functionality to ISQL

I did what was required with the help of WriteConsoleInput, all thanks for the help

Comment: `cin >> str;` ?

Comment: Unclear question. Show some [MCVE]. BTW, running programs (e.g. processes) might not even have any console (think of some Web server program like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) for example), and some Windows systems don't even have any screens (think of computers inside a datacenter)

Comment: Did you consider coding some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application (perhaps using [Qt](http://qt.io)...)? Or use [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)? Or some other terminal library (e.g. [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) ...)

Comment: the fgets function reads a string from the stream. I need that when performing fgets on the screen already had text that can be edited.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it (before it gets closed) but don't comment it. You can't do that with `fgets`. You could consider a GUI, or a full screen terminal application. And your program might not have any screen or console when running, so what you want is still unclear (you probably need some extra library, or to dive into the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)...)

Comment: Be aware that the [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) might not be the console (e.g. with [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) ....), and you need to define and think about what should be done in such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*... output to the console a string that the user could edit and press Enter*"

That's not what an standard console is supposed to do, and not what the standard C++ can do.

If you want to hack the console and write an editor, you have to play all a different game that depends on the type of console you are using (is it ANSI? i it the CMD? is it an XTerm?).

You'll probably get better result using a library like -for example- [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: I did what was required with the help of WriteConsoleInput, all thanks for the help

Comment: @СеменРоманов: Good to know you are on windows!